# How to set up Touch Bar to show function keys in a specific VirtualBox virtual machine

Tags: preferences, virtualbox, touch-bar

macOS allows you to change the Touch Bar to traditional function keys when you run specific applications. I have tried to do so with VirtualBox, and it works on the main VirtualBox window properly. The only issue is that when I launch a virtual machine, those settings lose their effect. The reason is that VirtualBox launches a differently-named executable file (from within its app bundle) in order to run the virtual machine in a separate process.

So, the question is: Is there a way to set up macOS to show the function buttons when running a virtual machine in VirtualBox (e.g. Linux or Windows)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.mastropaolo.com/2016/12/16/how-to-have-function-keys-in-virtualbox-guess-with-macos-touchbar/

> 1. Open a Finder window to the /Applications folder. Right click on VirtualBox.app and click “Show Package Contents”.
> 2. Find the Resources folder, and drag it into Finder’s favorites sidebar.
> 3. Using the Resources folder you put in favorites, add vmstarter.app and VirtualBoxVM.app to the list of exceptions.
> 4. Now you can remove the Resources shortcut you added to favorites.

Comment: Thanks, great! But according to the rules you need to bring the answer here (links are not sufficient) so that I can mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 6):

An approach that does not require the favorites sidebar is:

1. Open Settings
2. Pick Keyboard
3. Pick Shortcuts
4. Pick Function Keys
5. Press "+"
6. Type Command-Shift-G
7. Paste the text `/Applications/VirtualBox.app/Contents/Resources`
8. Select `VirtualBoxVM.app`

Similarly for `vmstarter.app`

Answer (score 1):

There is, as explained in the link anon provided: http://www.mastropaolo.com/2016/12/16/how-to-have-function-keys-in-virtualbox-guess-with-macos-touchbar/

1. Create a link to the actual executable:

   - Right-click "VirtualBox.app"
   - Click "Show Package Contents"
   - Find the "Resources" folder and drag it to the Finder's Favourites Sidebar
2. Add the executable to the list of Applications using the Function keys:

   - Open "Settings.app" and navigate to "Keyboard" ➝ "Shortcuts" ➝ "Function keys"
   - Click "+" and add "VirtualBoxVM.app" and "vmstarter.app" using the "Resources" folder in the sidebar.

You can then remove the link from the sidebar.